# Can I use \textit in the title of my arXiv submission?

Tags: publications, arxiv, latex

I need to italicize a word in the title of my submission. In the final preview page before submission on arXiv, the word is not being italicized rather I see:

> \textit{word}

This is the case for both title and abstract. Screenshot:
[arXiv submission page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUqzT.png)

Is there a solution for this?

For reference, https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.01521 has some LaTex text in the title.

Comment: You don't have full TeX support in the title field, https://arxiv.org/help/prep#title I've seen some people leave the \textit{} command in the title and let readers parse it, some just use math mode instead, and some just leave the fancy formatting out of the listing on the abstract page.

Comment: @Anyon Seems like an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with MathJax:

```
$\textit{word}$
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless it's absolutely unavoidable to use LaTeX in the title or abstract, don't. Lots of people use RSS feeds or other non-MathJax-enabled methods to browse the arXiv.